# Create a new Document object with custom URL

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to create a Document object with `URL` for it set to a specific custom value.
I've explored some options mentioned below but was not able to do it so far.

An example approach I've tried with an explanation of where it goes wrong and what I want instead:

```js
//run context is the browser on page http://localhost

// example URL value https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
const loadDocument = async (url: URL) => {
    // Fetching HTML from URL and parsing it into a document
    const docText = (await fetch(url)).text()
    const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(await fetchText(url.href), 'text/html')

    // the following will now be http://localhost, but I need it to be the URL the page is downloaded from 
    // i.e https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this
    console.log(doc.URL) 
    
    // the consequence of it being wrong is that any links to external resources using relative paths
    // would be wrong as-well
    
    console.log(doc.querySelector('link[rel="stylesheet"]').href)
    // will be "http://localhost/static/css/main.1baf2b3e.chunk.css"
    // instead of "https://developer.mozilla.org/static/css/main.1baf2b3e.chunk.css"
}
```

Main thing I'm trying to accomplish here is to have correct URLs on resources using relative links. I can try to manually fix this by walking over the DOM and changing URLs of anything that is using relative links to the original URL, but that seems error-prone. Hence - the hope to solve the problem in the root with setting the correct base URL on the document instead

---

Another thing I tried doing is `document.implementation.createHTMLDocument()` which results in a document with `about:blank` as URL, and no way to set it explicitly either =\

---

Trying to do an assignment to the URL property does not seem to do anything either (and it's explicitly marked as read-only in documentation)

Comment: Can you please post exactly what you require along with some more code or a working code for referance so it would be more clear. What you are getting when downloadig the Html and what actually you want to do with that.

Comment: The question is unclear and without more code and detail is impossible to answer.

Comment: Updated the question, I hope it's clearer now. If not - I'd appreciate you pointing out what specific part is confusing/doesn't make sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query those href properties you are actually getting their values to be relative paths that get evaluated to different absolute urls according to the context they are running. Since it would be crazy to walk through the entire dom and change that, I might suggest the opportunity to inject a base html element that will hint the basepath any relative url will be mapped to. It could quickly solve your specific problem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

> The <base> HTML element specifies the base URL to use for all relative
> URLs in a document. There can be only one <base> element in a
> document.

The condition must be that all those relative urls map to the same baseurl of course but that's for granted if you are grabbing the page from a working landing page url. Be warned that there are some constraints bound to CORS policies especially if the js on those pages will need to perform ajax queries to that domain. What I mean is that such solution doesn't gift you the keys to any possible scenario.

```
<base href="https://thereal.com/absolute/url">
```

Another interesting reading about the `baseURI` property from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/baseURI):

> The read-only baseURI property of the Node interface returns the
> absolute base URL of the document containing the node.
>
> The base URL is used to resolve relative URLs when the browser needs
> to obtain an absolute URL, for example when processing the HTML 
> element's src attribute or the xlink:href or href attributes in SVG.
>
> Although this property is read-only, its value is determined by an
> algorithm each time the property is accessed, and may change if the
> conditions changed.
>
> The base URL is determined as follows:
>
> - By default, the base URL is the location of the document (as    determined by window.location).
> - If it is an HTML Document and there is a `<base>` element in the    document, the hrefvalue of the first Base element with such an
>   attribute is used instead.

Comment: Nice, that's what I was looking for! A small snippet for people to copy-paste :

```typescript
function injectBase(doc: Document, url: URL) {
 let base = doc.querySelector('base')
 if (!base) {
  base = doc.createElement('base')
  doc.head.append(base)
 }
 base.href = url.href
}
```